# Tensorflow / Tensorboard missing output from one of hparams during profiling

Tags: tensorflow, tensorboard, tf.keras

TF / TB running a profile with the following setup :

```
HP_NUM_NODES_ONE = hp.HParam('nodes_one', hp.Discrete([128]))
HP_NUM_NODES_TWO = hp.HParam('nodes_two', hp.Discrete([64, 128, 256]))
HP_NUM_NODES_THR = hp.HParam('nodes_thr', hp.Discrete([64, 128, 256]))
HP_NUM_FILT = hp.HParam('num_filter', hp.Discrete([64, 128, 256]))
HP_DROPOUT = hp.HParam('dropout', hp.RealInterval(0.1, 0.3))
HP_OPTIMIZER = hp.HParam('optimizer', hp.Discrete(['adam', 'sgd', 'RMSprop']))

MSE = 'mean_squared_error'

with tf.summary.create_file_writer('logs/hparam_21-6').as_default():
  hp.hparams_config(
    hparams=[HP_NUM_NODES_ONE, HP_NUM_NODES_TWO, HP_NUM_NODES_THR, 
             HP_NUM_FILT, HP_DROPOUT, HP_OPTIMIZER],
      metrics=[hp.Metric(MSE, display_name='Mean Squared Error')],
  )
```

with this model :

```
def train_test_model(hparams):
    model = tf.keras.models.Sequential([
        tf.keras.layers.Conv1D(filters = hparams[HP_NUM_FILT], kernel_size=6, strides=1, 
                               activation='relu', input_shape=(300,4), use_bias=True),
        tf.keras.layers.MaxPooling1D(pool_size=100),
        tf.keras.layers.Flatten(),
        tf.keras.layers.Dense(hparams[HP_NUM_NODES_ONE], activation=tf.nn.relu),
        tf.keras.layers.Dropout(hparams[HP_DROPOUT]),
        tf.keras.layers.Dense(hparams[HP_NUM_NODES_TWO], activation=tf.nn.relu),
        tf.keras.layers.Dropout(hparams[HP_DROPOUT]),
        tf.keras.layers.Dense(hparams[HP_NUM_NODES_THR], activation="linear"),
     ])
    
    model.compile(
        optimizer=hparams[HP_OPTIMIZER],
        loss='mean_squared_error',
        metrics=['mean_squared_error'],
        )
    
    model.fit(feature3, label2[0,], epochs=500)
    _, mean_squared_error = model.evaluate(x_test, y_test[0,])
    return mean_squared_error
```

It all seems to run fine and I do get outputs, however the outputs in tensorboard do not show the results for different values of the "optimizer", which I want also.  Does it need to be treated/coded differently?  Happy to supply more of the code if this is not clear. Thx. J

Answer (score 0):

I found the problem, as simple as an unticked box in the tensorbox results!  So the standard results returned are:
[image: tensorboard, box unticked]

however is I simply tick the optimizer box, the results appear.
[image: tensorboard, box ticked]

I have no idea why tensorboard would, by default, turn this off.